# Инициализация вектора объектов (с конструктором, принимающим значения), являющегося членом класса

Tags: c++, c++11

Количество объектов класса MCP в векторе _rheos заранее неизвестно.
`std::vector` использую впервые. Ткните носом, пожалуйста, что не так. Не обязательно использовать вектор, но я другого решения для динамического массива объектов не нашёл.

```
class MCP
{
public:
    MCP (mbed::SPI& spi, PinName cs) : _spi(spi), _cs(cs) {}
private:
    mbed::SPI& _spi;
    mbed::DigitalOut _cs;
};
```

```
class Load
{
public:
    Load(uint8_t load_qty, mbed::SPI& spi, PinName rs) : _rs(rs)
    {
        for (register uint8_t i = 0; i < load_qty; i++)
        {
            _rheos.emplace_back(spi, NC);  //Здесь всё падает
        }
    }

private:
    mbed::DigitalOut _rs;
    std::vector<MCP> _rheos;
};
```

```
int main()
{
    mbed::SPI spi1(MOSI, MISO, SCK);
    Loads RLoads(7, spi1, BUTTON1); 
}
```

Компилируется успешно, но не работает.

Comment: А что такое `NC`?

Comment: `PinName NC = 0xFFFFFFFF;` //NC = Not Connected. Определено в пространстве имен mbed.

Comment: а может тебе вообще не нужен вектор. для контроллера то он нафига? что вообще твой код делает?

Comment: А вот это самое интересно. Пока только знаем, что оно не работает.

Comment: @Yakov, IoT нынче навороченный пошёл. STM32F7 это вам не ардуина.
Код делает: на интерфейсе SPI куча перефирии висит. В классах `MCP` и `Load` ещё куча членов, привёл только то, где столкнулся с проблемой. Если в кратце: В первом случае в самостоятельных объектах `MCP` есть статические массивы с данными, время от времени отправляемыми в SPI. Во втором случае в `Load` нужен динамический массив объектов `MCP` данные из которых будут отправляться по тому же SPI, но уже в другое место и в зависимости от значений переменных в `Load`.

Comment: ну попробуй вместо референса помещать в вектор указатель. на SPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что `MCP` не нравится `NC` в качестве `PinName`.
При этом, если, например, тот же `SPI` объявить как `spi2(MOSI, NC, SCK);` - то никаких проблем и всё работает.
Mbed-OS magic.